# maven multiple test suits in surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using TestNg and Maven with the surefire plugin to run my tests. I have several different tests that I want to run in the same pom. Currently to do this I have two different XML files defined and i've defined two profiles to run different xml files but this keeps throwing errors!

I don't know how I should solve this issue.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```xml
 <profile>
    <id>run</id>
     <activation>
        <property>
            <name>start</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
     </activation>
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                  <skip>true</skip>
                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.directory}/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                  </suiteXmlFiles>

                </configuration>
                 <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
</profile>
```

Imagine profile 2 to be pretty much the same BUT the xml suite file is different

I get a parsing error: It can't find the test class in the suiteXmlFile. However, if I just use one profile have just one xml file, it's acceptable. The one that was failing also works.

Comment: what is your goal, running multiple suites under one pom or running multiple suites under one pom with different profiles ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move suiteXmlFiles to execution configuration and use `maven-failsafe-plugin` that is more suitable for integration tests